# Add folders to .profile env vars

Tags: command-line, environment-variables

I have folder `~/Documents` which contains several scripts. For example 1 of them is `asleap`. So, its full path will be `~/Documents/asleap` and if i want to execute this script, I need to `./asleap` inside `~/Documents/asleap`.

Is it somehow possible to add all scripts to `.profile` with same logic (Path: `~/Documents/test` executable: `./test`, path: `~/Documents/test1` executable: `./test1`, etc) globally to shell? So I can execute `asleap`, `test` and `test1` everywhere?

Comment: Conventionally user scripts are placed in `~/bin` which has already been setup in `~/.profile` under Ubuntu. Your scripts would be better in this location if that sits well with your work flow.

Comment: There is a built-in command "test" so your script "test" will not be executed unless you specify a path, such as "./test".  I recommend that you rename "test" to something else.

Comment: Create symbolic links for each script you want to run by name in `~/Documents` to your `~/bin` directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put your scripts in `~/bin`, but, if you MUST keep the scripts in `~/Documents`, simply add `~/Documents` to your `PATH` in your `~/.bashrc`, like this:

```
PATH="$PATH:$HOME/Documents"
```

Comment: think you should reverse the order.

Comment: Why did you propose `~/.bashrc` for this, considering that code for this kind of `PATH` additions is already in `~/.profile`?